# Android - Play Sound on Button Click

Tags: android, button, audio, click, android-mediaplayer

I have been following an online tutorial on how to play sound on button click. I am getting no errors with my Java code which leads me to believe that the code is correct.

However, they did not provide a tutorial on what the xml should read. So I left it as it is but when the `Activity` loads nothing is occuring and I'm left with the Hello World Template.

Could somebody advise me how to get this code to run in the view and if so how. If not could they maybe provide me with an alternate option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in your XML you have a TextView, you should add a Button (actually you can just change TextView to Button in this case).  After that you need to either add

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

under the button.

Or you can use a onClickListener for the button.

Comment: Hi @Tristan Wiley , thank you for the reply I have done this and now I am getting an error of:

03-05 00:54:45.463: E/MediaPlayer(32067): Should have subtitle controller already set
03-05 00:54:45.472: W/MediaPlayer(32067): mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

Comment: What tutorial are you using?

Comment: http://www.aboutcodes.com/2013/06/android-code-for-playing-sound-in-button.html This one, thank you

Comment: Is the subtitle controller an error? Or is it just a warning.

Comment: It is appearing as an error. Once I remove

mysound.release();

The audio will play however I cannot stop the audio from playing?

Comment: How do you want the audio to stop playing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72285/discussion-between-tristan-wiley-and-meryl2).

Comment: Ideally through a different button but it could be the same button! Anyway which is feasible!